# Hit REST end point on startup - weblogic + ATG

Tags: rest, caching, weblogic, scheduler, atg

I have a rest endpoint which would start the scheduler of loading a XML to memory. Whenever I hit that rest endpoint, it loads the XML in memory and would return the XML after its ready (would take 10 - 15 seconds). When the same endpoint is accessed again, it would return the cached XML. Everything works fine but for now I have to manually hit the endpoint for the scheduler to start. Is there a way to hit the endpoint automatically via a simple code in startup? Or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Did you specify the Scheduler in your `Initial.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a component in the Nucleus is instantiated at first access, not at system start-up.

The way to have anything done at start-up in ATG is to create your component, and then to add its nucleus path to the list of initial services in the /Initial component (or from one of the many other `Initial` components changed off of it)

The component should be globally scoped. Because /Initial is instantiated at start-up, the services it references will also be instantiated as dependencies.

If your component is a POJO, then the no argument constructor will be invoked on component start-up, then the `setX` method will be called for each property with a value defined in its properties file.

If your component is extended from Generic Service, then additionally, `beforeSet` and `afterSet` methods will be called, before and after the set methods are invoked, if they exist, and finally `doStartUp` will be called.

This is all part of the fundamental lifecycle of components that the Nucleus manages.

This gives you a number of hooks with which to invoke your custom code.

Now, in your question, you ask how to call a REST endpoint at start-up. However, I believe what you actually want to ask is how to ensure that a particular piece of code gets executed at system start-up. A REST endpoint is how you are triggering it today, manually, from outside the Nucleus. But that does not mean that it must call a REST end point if it is to be automatically called at start up.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is

- define a class that extends `GenericService`
- override the `doStartUp` method
- put the code you want to execute in this method, or invoke the code on another component from here
- define a globally scoped component for the class
- Add the component to the `initialServices` property of the Initial component

Restart the server and check that your code is being called at start-up. Put some debug statements in, and switch debug logging on in your layer.

Note, you may actually also want to think about whether you really need to invoke your code at system start-up. Anything in initial services adds to the start time of the server. Depending on your requirements, it may be better to do it on first access of your application service rather than at server start-up.